# how to install additional usb drivers in WIX_INSTALLDIR type

Tags: wix

I have a wix file which is based on WixUI InstallDir type. Now i am able to make successful msi file. But i have got a new requirement that i should include an additional USB Drivers installation along with my msi package. i tried to search in google and came to know that there is Custom installation is required so I am little confused how to implement this, can some one help me in this regard please

Sample Code:

```
  <!--<UI>-->
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
    <Property Id ="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="__1.0" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="ABc_License_Agreement.txt" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="IEToolsSide_wix.bmp" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="IEToolsBanner_wix.bmp" />
  <!--</UI>-->

  <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
  <!--<MediaTemplate />-->
  <Media Id="1" Cabinet="Cab1.cab" EmbedCab="yes"/>

  <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="ABC IE Package R Ver 1.0" Level="1">
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    <ComponentRef Id="RegistryEntries"/>
  </Feature>
</Product>
```

Thanks
Ajaya

Comment: Where is the sample code??

Comment: i have updated the sample code.

Comment: @namezero can you suggest me some options to solve my issue ?

Comment: Use the WixUI_Advanced UI template instead of the WixUI_Installdir UI template - http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/dialog_reference/wixui_advanced.html

Comment: Could you provide some information on how the USB drivers are packaged?  Separate files? Standalone MSI/EXE? Something else?